# scroll top value changes when in developer mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a custom scrollbar for my web app.

The mechanism for my scrollbar is the default scrollbar is shifted right by 100px padding and it is hidden by `overflow:hidden` of the parent container

```js
$(".scrollbar-vertical").parent().children(".content").scroll(function(){
    
    scrollerHeight = (  $(this).parent().height() / $(this).prop("scrollHeight") ) * $(this).parent().height();
    //pad = $(this).css("padding-bottom").match(/[-\d]+/g)[0]*1+$(this).css("padding-top").match(/[-\d]+/g)[0]*1;
    sTop = ( $(this).scrollTop()  / ( $(this).prop("scrollHeight") - $(this).outerHeight()  ) * ( $(this).height() - scrollerHeight) );
    console.log($(this).scrollTop());
    $(this).parent().children(".scrollbar").children(".scroller").css({
        margin:sTop+"px"+" 0 0 0"
    });
});
$(".scrollbar-vertical").parent().children(".content").each(function(){
    scrollerHeight = (  $(this).parent().height() / $(this).prop("scrollHeight") ) * $(this).parent().height();
    $(this).parent().children(".scrollbar").children(".scroller").css({
        height:scrollerHeight
    });
    pad = $(this).css("padding-bottom").match(/[-\d]+/g)[0]*1+$(this).css("padding-top").match(/[-\d]+/g)[0]*1;
    if($(this).prop("scrollHeight")  - pad <= $(this).height()){
        $(this).parent().children(".scrollbar").hide();
    }
});
```

```css
.example{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    background:#eee;
}
.content{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:scroll;
    padding:0 100px 100px 0;
    margin:0 100px 100px 0;
    float:left;
}
.scrollbar-vertical{
    width:5px;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    right:0;
}

.scrollbar{
    transition:0.3s;
    background:transparent;
}
.scrollbar:hover{
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2) !important;
}

.scrollbar-vertical .scroller{
    width:100%;
    min-height:10px;
    background:#333 !important;
}


.scrollbar-vertical:hover{
    width:10px;
}

.scrollbar-horizontal{
    height:5px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    bottom:0;
}

.scrollbar-horizontal:hover{
    height:10px;
}

.scrollbar-horizontal .scroller{
    height:100%;
    min-width:10px;
    background:#333 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "example">
    <div class = "content">
        content..<br>
        content..<br>
        content..<br>
        content..<br>
        content..<br>
        content..<br>
    </div>
    <div class = "scrollbar scrollbar-vertical">
        <div class = "scroller"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This seems to work fine when the `overflow-y: scroll` is given for the `.content` but fails when `overflow: scroll` is given.

But even when the property `overflow: scroll` is given the scrollbar works fine in the developer mode in chrome browser.I have traced the problem to be the `$(this).scrollTop()` which is increased by 17 when not in developer mode.can anyone explain why this is happening? any help is appreciated

[codepen](https://codepen.io/megatroncoder/pen/RVVJdd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`17px` is the dimension of a scrollbar in Chrome on desktop (pointer type) displays. This amount of pixels is added to the actual dimension of your container when a scrollbar is present. And, in your example, it's present because you set it to always visible using `overflow:scroll`.

So the width of a vertical scrollbar is `17px`. And the height of a horizontal scrollbar is `17px`, in Chrome, on desktops.

The bars are hidden in developer mode because yo uhave pressed "Toggle device toolbar" - enabling preview of touch type devices when in developer mode. Therefore, Chrome adds mobile/touch scrollbars, which are rendered above the content and only visible when used. If your content does not require scrollbars (there's nothing to scroll) they are not shown at all, even if you set `overflow: scroll;` on the item.

You can toggle the device toolbar by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> while in developer mode.

Comment: is there a way to avoid this without affecting the program, and why does the scrollbar hide in developer mode?

Comment: It hides in developer mode because you have pressed the "Toggle device toolbar". I'll update my answer.